# I am trying to disable the entry after input is taken from the user by binding my Isenabled property of my model with the Isenabled property of Entry

Tags: xamarin.forms

The working looks correctly when the list starts but once the list is filled with more elements ie, when it needs to scroll for more elements the entry becomes disabled for all the remaining value in the UI , but when i check the model value for that particular entry its still true for `Isenabled` property

Here is my Xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="MyFirstApp.Demo">
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
<StackLayout>
<Button Text="Add" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
<ListView x:Name="DimensionListView" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<ViewCell >
<Grid>
<Grid x:Name="DimensionsGrid"  RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width ="0.9*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Entry  Text="{Binding Pieces }" IsEnabled="{Binding Isenabled}" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="0"  Grid.Column="0"   Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White"   TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
<Entry  Text="{Binding Length}" IsEnabled="{Binding Isenabled}" Keyboard="Numeric"  Placeholder="0"   Grid.Column="1"   Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White"   TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
<Entry  Text="{Binding Height }" IsEnabled="{Binding Isenabled}" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="0"  Grid.Column="2"   Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White"   TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
<Entry  Text="{Binding Width}" IsEnabled="{Binding Isenabled}" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="0"   Grid.Column="3"   Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="White"   TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
</Grid>
</ViewCell>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My Code behind :

```
namespace MyFirstApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class Demo : ContentPage
{
ShipmentViewModel ViewList = new ShipmentViewModel();
public Demo()
{
InitializeComponent();
ViewList.ShimpentDimsList = new ObservableCollection<VolumeCalculator>() { new VolumeCalculator() { Height = 0, Length = 0, Pieces = 0, Width = 0, Isenabled = true } };
DimensionListView.ItemsSource = ViewList.ShimpentDimsList;
}
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ViewList.ShimpentDimsList.LastOrDefault().Isenabled = false;
ViewList.ShimpentDimsList.Add(new VolumeCalculator() { Pieces = 0, Height = 0, Width = 0, Length = 0, Isenabled = true });
ObservableCollection<VolumeCalculator> TempList = ViewList.ShimpentDimsList;
}
}
}
```

My Model:

```
namespace MyFirstApp
{
class VolumeCalculator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private int pieces;
public int Pieces {
get { return pieces; }
set
{
pieces = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Pieces");
}
}
private int width;
public int Width
{
get { return width; }
set
{
width = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Width");
}
}
private int height;
public int Height
{
get { return height; }
set
{
height = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Height");
}
}
private int length;
public int Length
{
get { return length; }
set
{
length = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Length");
}
}
private bool isenabled ;
public bool Isenabled {
get { return isenabled; }
set
{
isenabled = value;
OnPropertyChanged("Isenabled"); 
}
}


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewMode:

```
namespace MyFirstApp
{
class ShipmentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private ObservableCollection<VolumeCalculator> shimpentDimsList;
public ObservableCollection<VolumeCalculator> ShimpentDimsList
{
get { return shimpentDimsList; }
set {
shimpentDimsList = value;
OnPropertyChanged("ShimpentDimsList");
}
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause :**  It caused by the **Caching Strategy** of the ListView .To conserve memory, the native ListView equivalents for each platform have built-in features for reusing rows. Only the cells visible on screen are loaded in memory and the content is loaded into existing cells. This pattern prevents the application from instantiating thousands of objects, saving time and memory.

**Solution :**  In your case , you need to set the **Caching Strategy** as `RecycleElement`

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" x:Name="DimensionListView" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
```

Comment: If this answer is helpful, please accept it (Just click the √ button on left side). Which will help others who have similar issue .

Comment: :Thanks for the solution,It was really helpful

Comment: Can you let me know for the same code how can i select the entry when i tap on the entry once it is disabled. @Lucas Zhang - MSFT